# jQuery validate not working for two fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate that both the domain field is correct and that the placeholder field has a value. Once both are true, the Submit button will show. Using jQuery validate, I can check that the domain is correct, but its not validating the placeholder field. The `playerClass` rule is not being applied:

```
$(function() {
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            playerClass: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            $("body").append("<p>Validation Complete!</p>");
        }
    });
});
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domainChk", function(value, element, params) {
        $(".submit").show();
        if (this.optional(element)) return true;
        var regExp = new RegExp("^(?!www\\.|http:\/\/www\.)(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$");
        return regExp.test(value);
    },
    function errmess(params, element) {
        $(".submit").hide();
        return "Valid hostname required for player code";
    });
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    domainChk: {
        domainChk: true
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/e04rca0t/)

Comment: JSFiddle is reporting that you are using "Bad Escaping" here : `var regExp = new RegExp("^(?!www\\.|http:\/\/www\.)(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$");` ( if you press "JS Hint" it validates your code for you ). Also, try pasting that regex into this website - https://regex101.com/. It doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, not showing up for me, it's passing validation correctly though. The issue is that the second field is not getting validated.

Comment: Sorry but, on your code where exactly are you testing the placeholder class for validation?

Comment: @quiuquio, the very beginning: 
`rules: {
            playerClass: {
                required: true
            }
        }`

Comment: [Not in your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/e04rca0t/).  In your fiddle you've declared `rules: { field: { required: true } }`

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of the jQuery Validate plugin?  1.8 must be about 5 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The playerClass rule is not being applied

Your second field, with `name="playerClass"` is not being validated because you've applied no validation rules to it.  There is no such rule called `playerClass` in your jsFiddle or in your OP, and you've applied no rules to the `playerClass` field in your jsFiddle.

Even if `playerClass` was a custom rule, the form is considered valid because the `playerClass` field is optional in your jsFiddle.  Without the `required` rule, when the field is left blank, it's valid.

You've also failed to close your `<form>` element in the jsFiddle.  There is no `</form>` tag.

---

**EDIT**:

As per documentation, **any `ajax()` should go inside the `submitHandler` function within the `.validate()` method.**

In other words, you are breaking the validation plugin with your `click` handler.

---

> I need to validate that both the domain field is correct and that the placeholder field has a value. Once both are true, the Submit button will show.

**Then why are you showing the submit button from within the `domainChk` rule?**  Once this rule is passed, you're showing the button with `$(".submit").show()`.

You would typically use the `.valid()` method to test the form and show/hide the button.

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('click keyup blur', function() {
    if ($('#form').valid()) {
        $(".submit").show();
    } else {
        $(".submit").hide();
    }
});
```

This is much closer to how it should be:  http://jsfiddle.net/e04rca0t/2/

Comment: This is very close, but there's an issue that when you validate the domain, enter a playerClass value, and then go back to the domain and clear it to fix the domain, the Submit button is still visible, when it should be set to invisible due to no value in the domain field.

Comment: @Matt, you can't simulate `.ajax()` in the jsFiddle so some things are not going to be demonstrable.  Anyway, I've got you close enough to where you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: @Matt, just like as explained in the first part of my answer, the `domain` field is not set to `required` so an empty `domain` field is a VALID form.  Simply set `domain` to `required`.  http://jsfiddle.net/e04rca0t/3/

Comment: Why does the submitHandler not get triggered?

Comment: @Matt, because you don't have a real submit button.  You need a `button` or `input` with `type="submit"` to trigger the `submitHandler` when the form is valid.  http://jsfiddle.net/e04rca0t/7/

Comment: Silly mistake...need more coffee! Thanks.